# formating PHP source code with DW?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

is there any way to format PHP code with dreamweaver.

so it looks clean neat??

Comment: spaces and tabs are always your friends :)

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver isn't really a PHP dev tool, while it can edit PHP files and do syntax highlighting it's more geared towards designers.

The PHP Developer Tools for Eclipse can do code formatting.